# Passing test arguments into mocha

Tags: npm, mocha.js

I want to run test with some arguments:

```
npm test option1
```

Script for test is mocha:

```
test: 'mocha'
```

I want to option1 to my mocha test. How do I do it? Or how can I get the arguments into run-script in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put `--` to mark the end of the npm arguments and the start of the arguments to be passed to your script. For instance:

```
npm test -- --foo
```

would run `mocha --foo` if your script for test is as you show in your question.